# Change Port Of PingFederate

Tags: pingfederate

By default **PingFederate** server runs on `9999` port. And we can change the subsequent **HTTPS** and **HTTP** port via Server Configuration in **PingFederate** dashboard.

But i have **JBoss** server using the same port `9999`. Although, I can change the **Jboss** port to something else,But i don't want to change it, instead i want to change the PingFederate server port to something else.

**Question :**

So, How can i change the port of **PingFederate** Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you pointed out, HTTPS on port 9999  is used by the Admin GUI by default. You can easily change it in your server's run.properties file. See the current docs for more info.

http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF71/Changing+Configuration+Parameters

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.. i totally missed that documentation